# Group array by subarray multiple subarray values

Tags: javascript, arrays, grouping, javascript-objects

I could really use a hand figuring out some complicated grouping logic in JavaScript.

I have this array, which contains a `schedule` subarray. I would like clone/group each object into its own object which is grouped by the `day` value.

Input:

```
[
  {
    "name": "John Doe",
    "schedule": [
      {
        "day": "monday",
        "time": "12:00"
      },
      {
        "day": "tuesday",
        "time": "12:00"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Jane Doe",
    "schedule": [
      {
        "day": "tuesday",
        "time": "14:00"
      },
      {
        "day": "wednesday",
        "time": "17:00"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Output:

```
{
  "monday": [
    {
      "name": "John Doe",
      "schedule": [
        {
          "day": "monday",
          "time": "12:00"
        },
        {
          "day": "tuesday",
          "time": "12:00"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "tuesday": [
    {
      "name": "John Doe",
      "schedule": [
        {
          "day": "monday",
          "time": "12:00"
        },
        {
          "day": "tuesday",
          "time": "12:00"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Jane Doe",
      "schedule": [
        {
          "day": "tuesday",
          "time": "14:00"
        },
        {
          "day": "wednesday",
          "time": "17:00"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "wednesday": {
    "name": "Jane Doe",
    "schedule": [
      {
        "day": "tuesday",
        "time": "14:00"
      },
      {
        "day": "wednesday",
        "time": "17:00"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: I've tried to use a groupBy function. Which partially does what I need it too. But it just don't go to the second object in the schedule array